# Can BrowserSync live reload hosts browser if executed through guest VM?

Tags: javascript, node.js, virtual-machine

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 host and a [Vagrant Ubuntu 14.04 Server](https://vagrantcloud.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64) Virtual Machine via Virtual Box.

I want to keep development tools like NPM's on the VM. One of those tools are [BrowserSync](https://github.com/shakyShane/browser-sync).

Can BrowserSync live reload a hosts browser if it's being executed through the guest?

https://github.com/shakyShane/browser-sync/issues/318

Comment: I myself would also like to know...did you figure it out?

Comment: I'd like to know how to do this as well.